# Mocking GitPython Repo Calls

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, gitpython

I've got a class with a function that adds unstaged changes in a git repo and commits them

```
    def commit_local_changes(self, repo_path):
        repo = Repo(repo_path)
        changed_files = repo.git.diff(None, name_only=True).splitlines()
        if changed_files:
            for file in changed_files:
                repo.git.add(file)
            repo.git.commit("-m", "some commit message")
        return repo.head.object.hexsha
```

I'm trying to write unit tests to go over this functionality and I was to have `repo.git.diff(None, name_only=True)` actually return something besides a mock. I've tried to set up the tests like so:

```
    
@patch("myModule.Repo")
def test_commit_local_changes(self, mock_repo):
       mock_repo.return_value
            .git.return_value
            .diff.return_value = 'file1\nfile2'
```

but when I print `changed_files` in the main method and call the mock I see that it's just some MagicMock:

```
<MagicMock name='Repo().git.diff().splitlines()' id='140551053340304'>
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- that is, code that we can copy and paste and run locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was a lack of understanding of Python's attribute mocking versus return value for a function result.

In my case, Repo() is a function creating an instance of the class Repo (python may have different names for these, I'm more familiar with Java). So I needed to mock the return value of Repo(), then Python will mock it's attributes for me, then I needed to mock the return value of the call to diff(). The following worked:

```
 mock_repo.return_value.git.diff.return_value = "file1\nfile2"
```